# One digit decimal lost (after period) with json stringify

Tags: json, typescript, protractor

I have a prepared data as json, with key:value pairs, like

```
   "FieldDefinition": {
                  "ReadOnly": true,
                  "MaxLength": 100,
                  "IsMultiline": false,
                  "IsPassword": true,
                  "IsFileSelect": false,
                  "IsScrollAllowed": false,
                  "IsCombined": false,
                  "TextFormat": {
                    "TextColor": "255, 0, 0",
                    "FontSizeInPt": 12.0,
                    "FontName": "Arial",
                    "Bold": false,
                    "Italic": false,
                    "TextAlign": "Left"
                  },
                  "Position": {
                    "PageNumber": 1,
                    "X": 119.900001525879,
                    "Y": 672.8358984375
                  },
```

after stringify the json "JSON.stringify(data)" the result will lost the decimal

```
"FieldDefinition":{"ReadOnly":true,"MaxLength":100,"IsMultiline":false,"IsPassword":true,"IsFileSelect":false,"IsScrollAllowed":false,"IsCombined":false,"TextFormat":{"TextColor":"255, 0, 0","FontSizeInPt":12,"FontName":"Arial","Bold":false,"Italic":false,"TextAlign
":"Left"},"Position":{"PageNumber":1,"X":119.900001525879,"Y":672.8358984375}
```

See example FontSizeInPt
12.0 became only 12 in result

Comment: `12` *is* the same as `12.0` after all. If you want to retain the decimal place, make it a string. If you don't have control over this, you can display the number as `myNumber.toFixed(1)` to get the decimal place displayed with it.

Comment: I got the data as a response body of an API call. And the goal is to compare the (full, long) result with a sample data (json). So I have no chance to manipulate this response data, unfortunately. I need to compare 12.0 with 12.0 but got only 12 in the response...

Comment: What I could do is to replace all values in response data as a post-action, like `requestBody.replace(/\.0,/g, ',')` and compare with sample data 12 (instead of 12.0)

Comment: There is no direct solution. The reason is if you run `console.log(12.0)` it returns `12`, so the issue has nothing to do with `JSON.stringify` its how js works. So your solution has to be rather a workaround. I can think of 2 approaches. 1. `.stringify()` takes multiple parameters, and the second parameter is `replacer` function. Research it if you can leverage it. Example of the use can be `if (key === 'FontSizeInPt') return value.toFixed(1)` 2. Use regex to find the value of FontSizeInPt after conversion and then replace it with `value.toFixed(1)`

Comment: Thank you, the interesting thing is that the decimal has lost, when it is fixed to 1.
See other values, like: "X":119.900001525879
Retrieved correctly.